# Restrict user access to specific com_content category

Tags: joomla-2.5, user, acl, access

I want to restrict user access to only one specific category for content component. I have an idea to create new user group, give access to this group to edit this one category and then assign user to this group. Is there any another solution than creating group?

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/how-to-restrict-access-to-custom-component-views/5406#5406

Comment: I'm looking for Administrator Panel solution

Comment: these triggers are available for admin section also

Comment: Would you like to restrict frontend (read) access or backend (write) access?

Comment: @HaraldLeithner - backend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways, I answer both ways each in separated answer.
This answer uses the exclude category variant. You have to create a new user group, set this user group as child of the “Manager” user group. Then you change the permission of each category to deny the access for this user group.

Here is a Step by Step tutorial (Joomla 2.5 because question is tagged with this version, it will work the same way in Joomla 3+):

1. Create the user group with “Manager” as parent
   [image: Add user group]
2. Create the user and add it to the new user group
   [image: Add user]
3. Change the permission of all categories (All child categories will have the same permissions, so maybe you wrap all categories in one and forbid the access there)
   [image: Change category permissions]
4. Create a category and allow the access to this group
   [image: Add new category]
5. Login with the new user and check the content component
   [image: User View]
6. Create a article
   [image: Add article with new user]

Comment: Very well written!

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 possible ways, I answer both ways each in separated answer.
This answer creates a complete new user group. You have to create a new user group, set this user group as child of the “Public” user group. Add the group to the “special” access level and allow the group to access the backend and the com_content. Then you change the permission of each category to allow the access for this user group.

Here is a Step by Step tutorial (Joomla 2.5 because question is tagged with this version, it will work the same way in Joomla 3+):

1. Create the user group with “Public” as parent
   [image: Add user group]
2. Add the user group to access level “Special”
   [image: Add access level]
3. Create the user and add it to the new user group
   [image: Create User]
4. Add the administrator access permission to the user group
   [image: Add backend permissions]
5. Add the permissions for the content component
   [image: Add component access]
6. Create a category and set the permissions for this category
   [image: Create category]
7. Login with the new User and check the content component
   [image: User View]
8. Create a article
   [image: Add article with new user]

Comment: Very well written, again!