# Can Joomla control access to a separate API which is behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: restful-api

I have a joomla site and wish to run a piece of vanilla Java-script (that I wrote) on this site.

The java script requires access to an API (which I have made).

I would much rather not have to implement a separate JWT system for this API as I anticipate technical problems syncing the two sets of permissions on the api and on the joomla site.

If I set up the API as a reverse proxy from the apache server can I use a custom joomla system plugin to control the access to the API?  A solution as described in this question perhaps?

[How to restrict access to custom component views?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/how-to-restrict-access-to-custom-component-views)

Or will this not work?  I don't really understand joomla enough to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently in Joomla! 3 you cannot do that.  Although TechJoomla have an API that you could use. https://techjoomla.com/rest-api-for-joomla

In Joomla! 4 you can use the inbuilt API as seen on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lT9qodsvfZg

I gave a bit of a fuller answer on another post:
[Crawling Joomla websites without parsing website's html](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/25059/crawling-joomla-websites-without-parsing-websites-html/29195#29195)